# Rewriting jquery function to accept different arguments?

Tags: jquery

I've created a function that looks for all li's with a class of "awesome", puts its data-superhero attribute to an array, and places it into a new ul.  How would I rewrite my code so that I have a function that accept parameters? This is what I originally came up with:

```
var myList = $("ul li.awesome").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("superhero")
}).toArray();

var list = $('<ul/>').appendTo('#newList');

function getHeros() {
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    list.append('<li>' + myList[i] + '</li>');
  }
}
getHeros();
```

Comment: How you structure the logic depends entirely on what you want the function (and it's arguments) to actually do...

Comment: with a function that accept parameters, you mean the function getHeros or the function map?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. I want the function to be able to go through my ul, find a whatever class name i input , and return its data-attributes into an ul

Comment: @LPZadkiel the function getHeros. Sorry i'm not good at explaining myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the code above the function to inside the function, provide names for the parameters between the parentheses. and use those names instead of the hardcoded values in the code. Finally, when you call the function, pass the value for each parameter.

I will use `className` and `dataAttr`, but you should change them to more meaningful names for your code:

```
function getHeros(className, dataAttr) {
  var myList = $("ul li." + className).map(function() {
    return $(this).data(dataAttr);
  }).toArray();

  var list = $('<ul/>').appendTo('#newList');

  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    list.append('<li>' + myList[i] + '</li>');
  }
}
getHeros("awesome", "superhero");
```